# Receive json data in an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Check my code shown below. I am posting some json to a controller method. And I want to receive the values in C# model class called `MenuItems`; but the problem is: I am able to post data to my controller, but all of my 'MenuItems' return null. Data is not being assigned properly. How can I fix it?

AJAX:

```
var obj = '[{ "text": "wewer", "target": "_self", "children": [{ "text": "wer", "target": "_top" }] }]';


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Custom/SaveMenu",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert(data); },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoWeb.ViewModels
{
    public class MenuItems
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string target { get; set; }
        public List<Child> children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string target { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveMenu(MenuItems menuItems)
{
    //'menuItems' this returns null for all properties

    //return Json("pokay");
}
```

Comment: You posting an array, so it needs to be `public JsonResult SaveMenu(IEnumerable<MenuItems> menuItems)` (note also, you have already stringified it so you don't need to use `JSON.stringify()` to do it again)

Comment: Alternatively, keep the existing parameter and remove the outer `[` and `]` so its an object, not a collection

Comment: Just apply `data: obj,` and remove `data: JSON.stringify(obj),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove `[` and `]` in first and last of `obj` .

So `obj` changed from :

```
var obj = '[{ "text": "wewer", "target": "_self", "children": [{ "text": "wer", "target": "_top" }] }]';
```

To this:

```
var obj = '{ "text": "wewer", "target": "_self", "children": [{ "text": "wer", "target": "_top" }] }';
```

And apply `data: obj`, and remove `data: JSON.stringify(obj),`

Full code :

```
var obj = '{ "text": "wewer", "target": "_self", "children": [{ "text": "wer", "target": "_top" }] }';


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Custom/SaveMenu",
        data: obj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert(data); },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `obj.slice(1, -1)` i did this then passing to controller now but still its null

Comment: @johnCogdle I tested my codes . Please replace my codes in your code. did you change `data: JSON.stringify(obj)` to `data: obj` ?